# Debug exec() PHP: "sh: *.exe : cannot execute binary file"

Tags: php, cmd, exec

I have a problem with `exec(*.exe ... 2>&1, $out)` in PHP. It ran perfectly in Localhost But when I upload hosting Linux, An error happen:
`"sh: *.exe : cannot execute binary file"`.
What did I do: 
 - php.ini checked : `;disable_functions = mai,system,passthru,shell_exec, *...`;
 - run perfectly in Localhost; ( `echo $out`,...)
 - check PATH ( full Path);
Please help me ...

Comment: Please can you add some more code, maybe any linked files you're using? Then we can fix your problem!

Answer (score 0):

exe ist a Windows File. You cannot execute an .exe File on Linux. This is only possible on Windows.

Comment: I run Windows executables on Linux webserver via wine.